# Node https.request to Docker API closes before full result is returned

Tags: node.js, docker, node-https

I'm trying to make a Node https.request to a Docker daemon on a remote machine. Everything works fine when connecting to daemons with around 40 containers (running or not running) - or when I limit the request to only return around 40 containers.

However, with no limit (all containers should be returned, basically a `docker ps -a` command) it seems that the connection ends before the full body has been returned. What I'm wondering is if this has got to do with how much Docker can return, or if I need to specify in my request to keep the connection alive for a longer response.

Here's my code so far:

```
var options = {
    hostname: server,
    port: port,
    path: path,
    method: 'GET',
    key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/**-client-key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/**-client-cert.pem'),
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
};

var request = https.request(options, function(result) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", result.statusCode);
    console.log("headers: ", result.headers);

    var resultBody = '';
    result.on('data', function(d) {
        resultBody += d;
    });
    result.on('end', function() {
        callback(resultBody);
    });

});

request.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});

request.write('data\n');
request.write('data\n');
request.end();
```

What happens is that the `result.on('end')` function is called before all data has been received.